# JQuery Masonry Float Left Issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I have a 2 columned website which works fine until I try to apply masonry id to my right hand column (The column I want masonry to be applied to).  My question is, how can I apply JQuery Masonry to a column which is floated left?  I've even tried putting the masonry id div inside of the floated column and it still doesn't work. Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Masonry applies to one DOM element. And it works with one div(element) at ones. You can apply Masonry to as many elements as you need:

```
$('#left-column-id').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item'
});
$('#right-column-id').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

or put all sortable elements in one div with `itemSelector` class name (named "item" in this example).